# widget does not get proper size when added to a layout

Tags: widget, width

I need to get the real width() of a widget when it is dynamically added to a layout, because I need to do some painting on the widget based on its width(). But the code below does not work as I expected: w.width() is always 640, which is obviously not the real width.
Any idea?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os, sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtGui import *  
from PyQt4.QtCore import * 

class MainWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUI()

    def setupUI(self):
        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(QLabel('label'))

    def minimunSizeHint(self):
        return QSize(30, 30)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(100, 100)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWidget()
    main.show()

    l = QGridLayout()
    l.addWidget(MyWidget(), 0, 0)
    l.addWidget(MyWidget(), 0, 1)
    l.addWidget(MyWidget(), 1, 0)
    l.addWidget(MyWidget(), 1, 1)
    main.mainLayout.addLayout(l)

    w = l.itemAtPosition(0, 0).widget()
    print w.width(), w.height()


    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just re-implement resizeEvent() and re-painting whenever the size changed.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os, sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtGui import *  
from PyQt4.QtCore import * 

class MainWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUI()

    def setupUI(self):
        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(QLabel('label'))

    def minimunSizeHint(self):
        return QSize(30, 30)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(100, 100)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        print self.width(), self.height()
        # call painting here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWidget()
    main.show()

    l = QGridLayout()
    l.addWidget(MyWidget(), 0, 0)
    l.addWidget(MyWidget(), 0, 1)
    l.addWidget(MyWidget(), 1, 0)
    l.addWidget(MyWidget(), 1, 1)
    main.mainLayout.addLayout(l)

    w = l.itemAtPosition(0, 0).widget()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```